# Missing some CSS stylings after sending the SendGrid dynamic mail

Tags: html, css, email, sendgrid

I created a dynamic email template in sendGrid. But the problmen is after sending the email some CSS stylings are missing. What are the best practices for guaranteeing that all CSS stylings (e.g. font size, line-height, font-family) are consistently preserved when sending a dynamic email template created in SendGrid? Are there any specific settings or approaches that need to be considered in order to ensure that the template is rendered properly on various email clients?